# Ubuntu 18.04 gets always abort when I type y,Y,yes

Tags: boot, command-line, networking, 18.04

Hello I use VPS hosting on Ubuntu 18.04 I want to installation things.

When it ask me to continue I type <kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd>,yes,-y but it returns always abort:
[image]

what can I do?

Comment: Why are you typing `-y` and not `y`?

Comment: I did both of them: y,Y

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `-y` when you call the command.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

There could be something about your VPS hosting but I'm not sure.

Comment: if my command is:sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove

How should i write?

Comment: I would write them one at a time due to the fact you are having problems. However it would be `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get -y autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key without typing any `y` and so on before it does the same thing as typing `y` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it's also quicker and easier than typing `y` or `yes`, etc.

Comment: see photos, i tried both  http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1808/13/a/a1f6b92a8915.jpg